Views для прохождения теста на Django
Кратко про проект: Нужно сделать веб-ресурс для оценки знаний(прохождения тестов)
Вот основные файлы
models.py
class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Название", max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    question_count = models.IntegerField("Количество вопросов", default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="author")

class Question(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, verbose_name="Тест", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    question_text = models.TextField("Вопрос")
    num_question = models.IntegerField("Номер вопроса:", default=1)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    answer_text1 = models.TextField("Текст першої відповіді")
    is_correct1 = models.BooleanField("Перша відповідь є правильною", default=False)
    answer_text2 = models.TextField("Текст другої відповіді")
    is_correct2 = models.BooleanField("Друга відповідь є правильною", default=False)
    answer_text3 = models.TextField("Текст третьої відповіді")
    is_correct3 = models.BooleanField("Третя відповідь є правильною", default=False)
    answer_text4 = models.TextField("Текст четвертої відповіді")
    is_correct4 = models.BooleanField("Четверта відповідь є правильною", default=False)

class Result(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Пользователь", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userResult')
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test,verbose_name="Тест", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='testResult')
    score = models.IntegerField("Оценка")

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ShowTestView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
    path('test/add/', views.CreateTestView.as_view(), name='test_add'),
    path('test/<int:pk>/pass/', views.PassTestView.as_view(), name='test_pass'),
    path('test/<int:pk>/update/', views.UpdateTestView.as_view(), name='test_update'),
    path('test/<int:test_id>/add/', views.CreateQuestionView.as_view(), name='question_add'),
    path('test/<int:test_id>/add/<int:question_id>/', views.CreateAnswerView.as_view(), name='answer_add'),
    path('test/<int:test_id>/result/', views.TestResultsView.as_view(), name='test_result'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name = 'contact'),
]

forms.py
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'question_count']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'question_count': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_text', 'num_question']
        widgets = {
            'question_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'num_question': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['answer_text1', 'is_correct1', 'answer_text2', 'is_correct2', 'answer_text3', 'is_correct3', 'answer_text4', 'is_correct4']
        widgets = {
            'answer_text1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_correct1': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input mb-5'}),
            'answer_text2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_correct2': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input mb-5'}),
            'answer_text3': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_correct3': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input mb-5'}),
            'answer_text4': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_correct4': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input mb-5'}),
        }

class PassTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ['score']
        widgets = {
            'score': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PassTestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

views.py
class PassTestView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        test = get_object_or_404(TestModels, pk=pk)
        questions = test.questions.all()
        form = PassTestForm()
        return render(request, 'courses/pass_test.html', {'test': test, 'questions': questions, 'form': form})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        test = get_object_or_404(TestModels, pk=pk)
        form = PassTestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            score = 0
            for question in test.questions.all():
                selected_answers = request.POST.getlist(f'question_{question.id}')
                correct_answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=question, is_correct=True)
                if set(selected_answers) == set(str(answer.id) for answer in correct_answers):
                    score += 1
            result = Result.objects.create(user=request.user, test=test, score=score)
            messages.success(request, 'Результати тестування збережено успішно.')
            return redirect('test_results', test_id=pk)  # Ось тут змінено ім'я шляху
        else:
            questions = test.questions.all()
            return render(request, 'courses/pass_test.html', {'test': test, 'questions': questions, 'form': form})


class TestResultsView(View):
    def get(self, request, test_id):
        results = Result.objects.filter(test_id=test_id)
        context = {
            'results': results,
        }
        return render(request, 'courses/test_result.html', context)

pass_test.html
{% block content %}
    <h1 class="mb-5">{{ test.title }}</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for question in questions %}
            <div class="mb-5">
                <h2 class="mb-3">Питання №{{ question.num_question }}: {{ question.question_text }}</h2>
                {% for answer in question.answers.all %}
                    <div class="form-check ml-4 mb-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="answer{{ answer.id }}" name="question{{ question.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="answer{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.answer_text1 }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check ml-4 mb-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="answer{{ answer.id }}" name="question{{ question.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="answer{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.answer_text2 }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check ml-4 mb-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="answer{{ answer.id }}" name="question{{ question.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="answer{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.answer_text3 }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check ml-4 mb-2">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="answer{{ answer.id }}" name="question{{ question.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="answer{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.answer_text4 }}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-pill px-3">Завершити тест</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

Ошибка в том что при нажатии кнопки закончить тест мы остаемся на странице прохождения теста(кнопка = submit)
Может ошибка очень простая, я гуглил, решения не нашел, доп файли прикреплю если надо

а html-template ваш где?

Какой именно? Отображения тестов или результата?

тот , в котором у вас кнопка submit, которая не работает так, как надо.

Добавил, тут html прохождения теста

ну вот я вижу, метод вы указали в теге form. а action где? куда должен браузер переходить по нажатию кнопки?
